# How to solve the recurrence relation $ a_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_{i}a_{n-i} $

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

The relation is:
$$
a_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_{i}a_{n-i}\\n>1,a_1=2
$$

I know I probably should create a generating function for $a_n$, like $G(x)=f(x)*g(x)$, but I'm not sure what $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exactly should be, are they just $\sum a_ix^i$ and $\sum a_{n-i}x^{n-i}$ ? And are there any other methods to solve it? Any hint would be useful to me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Do you know about Cauchy products of power series?

Comment: @Gary I only have a vague memory about it. I look it up, so the generating function should just be ∑a_i*x^i\* ∑a_j\*x^j(i,j ->∞) right? Thanks!

Comment: More or less. You have to be a bit carfeul because the recurrece is only valid for $n\geq 2$. Note also that by setting $a_0=0$ you can extend the sum from $i=0$ to $n$ in your recurrence and get the complete convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use generating functions to solve this recurrence relation. We set according to the stated recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
A(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n=2x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ia_{n-i}\right)x^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Note we start the generating function with $2x$ since the recurrence relation has initial condition $a_1=2$.

> Since
> \begin{align*}
> \left(A(x)\right)^2&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^k\right)\left(\sum_{l=1}^\infty a_lx^l\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 1}}a_ka_l\right)x^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_ka_{n-k}\right)x^n\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> we obtain from (1) and (2) the functional equation
> \begin{align*}
> \left(A(x)\right)^2=A(x)-2x
> \end{align*}
> Solving this quadratic equation we find
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{1-8x}\right)}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> where we take the *minus* sign, since this provides a generating function with constant term zero.

*Note:* Evaluating the first few terms $a_n$ gives
\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{1-8x}\right)\\
&=2x+4x^2+16x^3+80x^4+448x^5+\cdots
\end{align*}
We find the sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\geq 1}$ stored as *[A025225](https://oeis.org/A025225)* in OEIS. There's also an explicit expression given for $a_n$:
\begin{align*}
a_n=\frac{2^n}{n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\qquad n=1,2,\ldots
\end{align*}
which can be easily derived from (3) and we find a strong connection with the ubiquituous *[Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)*.

Comment: So: another way to find this would have been:  compute the first $10$ of these, plug into OEIS and see what comes up.  https://oeis.org/

Comment: @GEdgar: Correct, but since OP is addressing generating functions, I think an answer providing a bit more related information might be advantageous.